# Strong consistency of kernel density estimator

Tags: estimation, nonparametric, convergence, kernel-smoothing, consistency

I am studying the book *Nonparametric and Semiparametric Models* written by Wolfgang Hardle and have difficulty with the following exercise:

> $\textbf{Exercise 3.13}$ Show that $\hat{f_h}^{(n)}(x) \xrightarrow {a.s.}f(x)$. Assume that $f$ possesses a second derivative and $\Vert K \Vert_2 <\infty$.

where $\hat{f_h}^{(n)}(x)=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n K_h(x-X_i)$ is the density kernel estimator, $\Vert K \Vert_2=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}K^2(s)ds\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and we set $h=O\left(n^{-\frac{1}{5}}\right)$ which is the optimal bandwidth parameter in this exercise.

Here is my attempt: I want to use Borel-Cantelli lemma to prove the almost sure convergence. By Chebyshev's inequality, we have

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\vert \hat{f_h}^{(n)}(x)-f(x)\vert>\epsilon\right)\le \dfrac{\mathbb{E}\left(\hat{f_h}^{(n)}(x)-f(x)\right)^2}{\epsilon ^2}=\dfrac{MSE\left(\hat{f_h}^{(n)}(x)\right)}{\epsilon^2},
$$
and it is known that
$$
MSE\left(\hat{f_h}^{(n)}(x)\right)=\dfrac{f(x)}{nh}\Vert K \Vert_2^2+\dfrac{1}{4}(f''(x))^2h^4(\mu_2(K))^2+o(h^4)+o\left(\dfrac{1}{nh}\right)
$$
where $\mu_2(K)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}s^2K(s)ds$. By replacing $h$ with $h_{opt}=O\left(n^{-\frac{1}{5}}\right)$ we derive that $$MSE\left(\hat{f_h}^{(n)}(x)\right)=O\left(n^{-\frac{4}{5}}\right)$$
However, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-\frac{4}{5}}=\infty$ and I was stuck here. Can anyone help me with this?